# How to set double precision values in Fortran

Tags: fortran, floating-point

Recently, I've encountered a bizarre problem with FORTRAN95.  I initialized variables X and Y as follows:

```
X=1.0
Y=0.1
```

Later I add them together and print the result:

```
1.10000000149012
```

After examining the variables, it seems as though 0.1 is not represented in double precision with full accuracy.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Another way to do this is to first explicitly specify the precision you desire in the variable using the [SELECTED_REAL_KIND](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fREAL_005fKIND.html) intrinsic and then use this to define and initialize the variables. Something like:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15)
REAL(dp) :: x
x = 1.0_dp
```

A nice advantage to doing it this way is that you can store the definition of `dp` in a module, then `USE` that module where needed. Now if you ever want to change the precision of your program, you only have to change the definition of `dp` in that one place instead of searching and replacing all the `D0`s at the end of your variable initializations. (This is also why I'd recommend not using the `1.0D-1` syntax to define Y as suggested. It works, but makes it harder to find and change all instances in the future.)

[This page](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision) on the Fortran Wiki gives some good additional information on `SELECTED_REAL_KIND`.

Comment: That's right, this should be the standard approach.

Comment: And how often do people really have to change the precision on their programs blindly without going procedure by procedure anyway and testing? The main reason to use the `_dp` scheme is so that the precision is clearly defined in a portable way.

Answer (score 13):

You declared the variables as double precision, but you initialized them with single precision values.

You could have written:

```
X=1.0d0
Y=1.0d-1
```

[Barron's answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/973/81) below is another way of making a literal double precision, with the advantage that it allows you to change the precision of your variables at a later time.

Comment: I think that one should be using the 1.0_dp method described in the post below.

Comment: I second @OndřejČertík 's comment - Barron's answer is the best one.